# CSS 100% height columns, but with page still scrollable

Tags: css

I have a traditional 3-column layout: nav, content and sidebar.

The content and sidebar both have a background-color that needs to cover 100% of the visible height at all times, regardless of how much content is in it. In other words, the background should remain there when scrolling down, or resizing the page.

Please see this jsfiddle for reference: http://jsfiddle.net/thv20/acJVw/1/

The problem is that when you scroll down or resize, the background cuts off. How can I fix this? I've seen suggestions of using `min-height: 100%`, but I can't get that to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove "height: 100%" off the body tag as this is what is breaking your layout.

Instead, use `position: absolute` on the side bar and position it `top:0` `bottom: 0` as this will make its height "100%". Also set `right: 0` to position it on the right hand side of the container div (this is safe to do as you have set widths).

#### CSS

```
#container {
    position:relative;   /*add this to use position:absolute on child element */
    overflow: hidden;    /*add this to clear your floats*/
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid black
}

nav, section{ 
    float: left; 
    width: 200px;
}

section {
    background: red;
}

sidebar {
    background: green;
    position:absolute;     /*add this and positions below */
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
}
```

**JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/acJVw/6/**

Comment: Hmm, just realised this breaks badly if the content area has less text in it than the sidebar. It should still cover 100% height in this situation: http://jsfiddle.net/thv20/acJVw/7/

Comment: Yes, unfortunately with that approach the parent div dictates the height of the absolutely positioned div. You could get around this by adding a couple of filler divs instead : http://jsfiddle.net/acJVw/9/

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how complex your background is, you could use a background image that has the page's width and is filled with the colors you like for your columns, set it as the page's background and repeat it ([Faux Columns by Dan Cederholm](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/)).

You might also position you columns absolutely and set `top:` and `bottom:` to `0` but that's just off the top of my head. I don't know if that works cross browser, though.

```
.sidebar
{
    position: absolute;
    widht: 200px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, what you want is a background color that is fixed in window and doesn't move when scrolling. Is this what you want?

If yes, I suggest you create a div classed 'whatever' and in your CSS file:

```
div.whatever
{
    position:fixed;
    z-index:-1;
    background-color:red;
    height:100%;
    top:0;
    left:/*you choose */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A hack :

If you make

```
 body, html, #container, nav, section, sidebar {height:1000%;}
```

Then it will appear to work, but this completely depends on the resolution of the user screen.

Comment: I would not recommend doing this.