# Min-height in CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css

I am still working on my site and I finally got the sticky footer to work. The next problem is that I want the columns to be filling up everything until the footer starts. No whitespace from the bottom of the columns to the top of the footer.

[Here is my example](http://jsfiddle.net/RP5Uk/)

**Html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>In ontwikkeling!</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/basis.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="menu">
        Menu
    </div>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="header">
            Header
        </div>
        <div id="sidebar-l">
            <div class="padding">
                Sidebar Links
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="sidebar-r">
            <div class="padding">
                Sidebar Rechts
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="content">
            <div class="padding">
                Content
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="push"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        Footer
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
/* CSS-file behorend bij TNG */

html,body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#menu{
    background-color:rgb(255,86,81);
    height:50px;
}

#container{
    width:1000px;
    margin:auto;
}

#header{
    background-color:rgb(224,17,80);
    height:150px;
}

#sidebar-l{
    background-color:rgb(141,171,242);
    width:280px;
    float:left;
    position:fixed;
    height:100%;
}

#sidebar-r{
    background-color:rgb(141,171,242);
    width:220px;
    float:right;
    height:100%;
}

#content{
    background-color:rgb(39,85,92);
    margin-left:280px;
    margin-right:220px;
}

#sidebar-l .padding, #sidebar-r .padding, #content .padding{
    padding:10px;
}

#footer{
    background-color:rgb(84,48,64);
    width:1400px;
    height:66px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-700px;
    bottom:0;
    position:fixed;
    clear:both;
}

.push{
    height:66px;
}
```

When you look at the sidebar on the left, I want the content and "sidebar rechts" to be the same.
The CSS and HTML are all on the link above!

Comment: Erik, thank you for putting the code here! I will keep that in mind for possible further questions.

Comment: You might need to re-structure your html/css - this tutorial may help: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks

Comment: web_bod: I'm not that good at HTML/CSS as you might've seen, haha! I will follow the tutorial and try again. ;)

Comment: If you're serious about this endeavor, I'd appreciate if you reviewed my answer. I spent a good deal of time on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I borrowed from the chosen answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8377193/css-100-height-columns-but-with-page-still-scrollable) and came up with this:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RP5Uk/7/)

Basically, there's absolutely-positioned, stretchy, dummy elements behind the columns so that no matter how tall the browser window is, their background color will always fill the whitespace.

Amongst the other various improvements I made to the code, I made the [sticky footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/) *actually* sticky now, in that it adjusts to the content above it. Resize the panel window to observe.

Comment: Dear gmeben,

I am sorry for the late response! I really like your solution, I'll use your framework to build the website completely. Thank you very much, I will upvote your answer.